# UHF RFID enter/leave detection

Tags: rfid, detection

I want to create a kit which can detect if a person is entering or leaving a room. During my research I decided to use RFID UHF technology. The kit's content:

- Two antennas placed next to each other
- One reader to connect these antennas
- Passive tags

Main idea is to check which antenna will detect a tag earlier. Thanks to that it should be possible to obtain the tag's movement direction.

I was thinking to use M6E-M-DEVKIT (here is the specification: http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/ThingMagic%20PDF%27s/MERCURYDevKit.pdf)

Can you tell me if this has a chance to work?

Comment: What is two people will approach the door at the same time?

Comment: Aren't rfid readers capable of detecting more than one tag at the same time? But even if they're not, it's not so necessary, so it;s not a big problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this has a perfect chance to work, have seen this work multiple times.

A separation of around 1 meter between the antennas should work, but the larger, the better.

Please note that with UHF RFID the radio field is not strongly limited: due to reflection and interference you might see reads when you do not expect them, and the other way around. You should take this into account when making a software algorithm.

The ThingMagic devkit is a great start, but it should work with any commercial reader available.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the cost of two one-channel readers is much cheaper than the cost of one two-channel reader. Will it make any difference? I'm afraid of problems with synchronization. If I had to choose a two-channel reader I will buy SkyeTek SuperNova and antennas like this one: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/2dbi-small-uhf-rfid-Antenna-Ceramics-for-iso-passive-epc-gen2-desktop-uhf-rfid-reader-rfid/32270684559.html. What do you think about it?